# NIFI is unable to connect to URL with https using invokeHTTP Processor, no certificate is required to access the site via browser(only user & pass)

Tags: apache-nifi

NIFI is unable to connect to URL with https using invokeHTTP Processor, no certificate is required to access the site via browser(only user & pass).

The error observed is "Request Processing Failed: javax.net.SSLPeerUnverifiedException".
I have tried adding SSL Context with Java Truststore and nifi Keystore. But it is not working.Kindly suggest.

Comment: Please add more details of the error message you're seeing, as it sounds like configuring the Java truststore should be sufficient

Answer (score 0):

When using InvokeHTTP to connect to a HTTPS URL, you will need to add an SSLContextService which InvokeHTTP can use to verify the remote server. The SSLContextService will refer to a truststore which contains the public Certificate Authority. For example if connecting to stackoverflow with NiFi, you would need the *CN = ISRG Root X1, O = Internet Security Research Group, C = US* installed in a pkcs12 truststore, which is used by the SSLContextService. Another option is to use the truststore provided by Java, typically located at $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts, which will trust most publicly signed web domain certificates.

Please add more details of the error message if this still is not working.